# Can a property setter use open array parameter?

Tags: delphi

The doc says dynamic arrays can be passed into a function/procedure using open array parameters.

For example, the following works, in accordance with the doc.

```
type
  TAInteger = array of Integer;

function Work(const A: array of Integer): Integer;
begin
  Result := Length(A);
end;
```

However, the code below complains about `E2008 Incompatible types`:

```
type
  TTest = class
  private
    procedure SetIntegerArray(const Value: array of Integer);
  published
    property Value: TAInteger write SetIntegerArray;
  end;
```

I am confused why there is the "Incompatible types" error, and whether a [property setter](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Properties) can use open array parameters ?

Comment: FWIW, if you are using a modern Delphi, then `TArray<Integer>` will give you much more flexibility than a bespoke dynamic array type

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Why did you roll back my edit ? What I did is the simply adding the link of the official doc. The original question is not touched.

Comment: You added more. The word no. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can a property setter use open array parameter?

No.

The type of the parameter that contains the new property value must be compatible with the property's type. An open array is not a type. Your property setter must be written like this:

```
procedure SetIntegerArray(const Value: TAInteger);
```